# Pivoting a very large table with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I want to create a new table from two other tables. The problem is that I have too many columns and it makes everything crash.

The first table I have is a "connection" between users and objects.

```
Table User

|  id  | user_id  | o54879  |  o54880  | o87984  | ...
--------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |  25488   |   0     |     1    |    0    | ...
--------------------------------------------------------
|  2   |  35487   |   0     |     1    |    1    | ...
--------------------------------------------------------
```

The 2nd table assigns each object to a category:

```
Table Cat

|  id  |  object_id  | category |
---------------------------------
|  1   |   o54879    |    1     |
---------------------------------
|  2   |   o54880    |    2     |
---------------------------------
|  3   |   o56457    |    2     |
---------------------------------
|  4   |   o59782    |    7     |
---------------------------------
```

What I want is a 3nd table like this.

```
Table UserGroupedByCat

|  id  | user_id  |  c1  |  c2  |  c3   | ...
---------------------------------------------
|  1   |  25488   |  0.4 |  0.1 |  0.7  | ...
---------------------------------------------
|  2   |  35487   | 0.01 | 0.75 |  0.2  | ...
---------------------------------------------
```

c1, c2, c3 ... should be the mean that a user has for each category.

The main problem is that I have like 500 objects in the database and I makes everything crash when I try to built a sql query like this one:

```
INSERT INTO UserGroupedByCat (user_id, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, c7) 
   SELECT user_id, 
      ((o34508629+o52965151+o52630004+o34518676+...)/<sum of all objects>),      
      ((o62846406+o50349529+...)/<sum of all objects>), ...
   FROM `User`;
```

**Is there a better (faster) way to make such a query?**

Comment: What do you mean by 'makes everything crash'?  Do you get some sort of error message?  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Well I can wait for two hours and the computer is not responding.

Comment: *Well I can wait for two hours and the computer is not responding* have you at least added log messages (probably using a logger or the naive `System.out.println`) to get sure your application is not working at all?

Comment: Yes, I did. I've also tried my code on a smaller database and It works.

Comment: Can you post your whole SQL query please?  At the moment it looks like your summing every value for every user, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I would rebuild your first table with just 3 columns (you can have a numerical ID too, but I see you don't use it anyway):

```
USER_ID CATEGORY_ID SCORE

25488   o54879  0
25488   o54880  1
25488   o87984  0
...
35487   o54879  0
35487   o54880  1
35487   o87984  1
...
```

That would make your system quite more scalable and should take away those problems you talk about